# order by a specific field and another field if empty in TYPO3 extension

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, typo3

I have stumpled upon a problem I can't figure out. I am making a list of prices for products where it take the prices from three columns `(price1, price2, price3)` where each price column is for a specific version of that product.

Some of the products might not have a price in price 1 as it doesn't exist in that version and a few products only have a price in price3.

Have can I get an ORDER BY that will list the products ordered by prices, so if a product that have the price 5400 only in price3 will be listed after the product that have the price 5300 in price1.

If I ORDER BY price1, the products that that doesn't have a price in price1 will get listed at the top.

I am using the TYPO3 extension overlays where by SQL statement is

```
tx_overlays::getAllRecordsForTable('*', 'tx_rtmur_bricks', $where, '', 'price1 ASC');
```

the '' after where is GROUP BY

EDIT:

This is how it is listed now:

```
Product 472
Price pr 1000 pcs: 7.730 in version 3

Product 201
Price pr 1000 pcs: 5.690 in version 1
Price pr 1000 pcs: 7.315 in version 2

Product 301
Price pr 1000 pcs: 5.690 in version 1
Price pr 1000 pcs: 7.315 in version 2

Product 309
Price pr 1000 pcs: 6.760 in version 1
Price pr 1000 pcs: 7.350 in version 3
```

I want it to be sorted this way:

```
Product 201
Price pr 1000 pcs: 5.690 in version 1
Price pr 1000 pcs: 7.315 in version 2

Product 301
Price pr 1000 pcs: 5.690 in version 1
Price pr 1000 pcs: 7.315 in version 2

Product 309
Price pr 1000 pcs: 6.760 in version 1
Price pr 1000 pcs: 7.350 in version 3

Product 472
Price pr 1000 pcs: 7.730 in version 3
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how you want the results ordered. Paste the result of the current results and show us how you want to change it..

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is another answer for you. I still recommend the previous one, and refactoring your code and your database will take some work put it is not impossible. The upgrade script for your data base should be fairly straight forward to write, so you can keep all your data..

Anyways here is a solution. Again you have to translate the field names cause I built this using my own test set:

```
select * from 
 (select id as id, "version 1" as version , price1 as price from tx_rtmur_bricks
    where price1 is not null
  union 
   select id, "version 2", price2 from tx_rtmur_bricks where price2 is not null 
  union 
   select id, "version 3", price3 from tx_rtmur_bricks where price3 is not null
 ) p 
group by p.id, p.price asc;
```

So you see how much more complex it becomes..

You might have to tweak the group by params and add some columns to the selects to get exactly what you want..

Edit: The result should be something like:

```
Product, Version, Price
123, "Version 1", 5.50
123, "Version 3", 7.50
134, "Version 1", 5.50
134, "Version 2", 6,50
154, "Version 3", 8,50
etc
```

Comment: This seems to do some of the right thing, but it only display one price, where I want to display the price for each version of each product..  If a product have to versions it will display price1 and price3 and only price 1 or price2 for another product.

Comment: It will display one row for each version, just like in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend refactoring your database structure and create a separate table for product version where the prices are included:

```
Product_version:
id,
productId (foreign key),
version (name or number..),
price
```

That would make these kind of queries simpler and it is easier to manage when you have more or less then exactly 3 versions..

Your query would be something like:

```
select * from product p 
inner join version v on p.id = v.pid 
group by p.id,  price asc;
```

Comment: Argh.. I feared that answer.. I have about 80 products with about 2 prices each and 3 languages.

The DB structure was made the way it is because it only was supposed to be 2 prices in one language and I could ORDER BY price1.

Didn't take this into account.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot since i cannot test this right now. But maybe you can order by CASE?

```
SELECT * FROM Product
ORDER BY ProductID, CASE WHEN Price3 IS NULL THEN
CASE WHEN Price2 IS NULL THEN Price1 ELSE Price2 END ELSE Price3 END
```